# Installing FFTW library on a non-unix system using MinGW 64-bit

Tags: c, mingw, fftw

I am having trouble  installing the FFTW library on Windows. I am following instructions from the following link:

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-non_002dUnix-systems.html#Installation-on-non_002dUnix-systems

1)
After downloading minGW 64-bit, I was wondering  how I would access the "kernel" and "simd-support" directory to compile the c files as recommended.

2)
As I am unfamiliar with this library, is there a better way of installing the library using the command line?

As written in this link, under the subtitle "building FFTW3 under minGW":

http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

when I run the following commmand:

```
./configure --with-our-malloc16 --with-windows-f77-mangling --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-portable-binary --enable-sse2 --with-incoming-stack-boundary=2
```

I get:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not use the precompiled DLLs?

Answer (score 1):

For FFTW 3.3.10, I installed Cygwin with the mingw64-gcc package.  From within the Cygwin command window, I set the following two variables:

```
export CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
export AR=x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar.exe
```

Next, I added "#define FFTW_DLL" to the fftw3.h header before building.  I configured the build with the following command:

`./configure --prefix=/cygdrive/c/fftw-build --with-our-malloc16 --with-windows-f77-mangling --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-sse2 --enable-avx --enable-avx2 --enable-avx512 --enable-avx-128-fma --with-incoming-stack-boundary=2 -disable-fortran --disable-alloca`

and then I ran

```
make
make check
make install
```

Once that was done, the resulting desired DLL was in the `bin` directory, not the `lib` one.  I followed the instructions in `BUILD-MINGW64.sh` from the fftw.org website to create the .def text file, and ran

```
lib /machine:x64 /def:libfftw3-3.def
```

on that text file to get the required .lib.  VS2017 seems to be happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are running your configure script in the cmd/power shell. You have to run your configure command in the MinGW shell.
2. http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html has prebuilt libraries. They offer well maintained and optimised builds for 32bit and 64bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely certain this answer is too late to help, but I still wanted to demonstrate how I solved this problem for myself in case it helps somebody in the future. As a quick note, **I have verified that the solution I am about to offer works on Linux, but not that it works on Windows**. However, I still offer this solution under the assumption that the process will be relatively - if not exactly - the same on both operating systems (both use MinGW). Excuse me if I use some incorrect/innacurate terminoligy, as I am not a professional developer.

I'll start by addressing the said error message: **'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command**. I'm much more familiar with the Linux command line, but my interpretation of this error is that the executable you are trying to run - **configure** - cannot be found by the system. The two obvious explanations for this are 1) The executable has not been installed or 2) The executable is installed in a different directory from the one you are currently in *(as a later edit, I've realised that you don't need to put **./** in front while running executables in Windows - you just type the name; also, I hadn't thought of this before but Windows directories are seperated by **\** rather than **/**, which is another likely reason for the error)*. This leads me to...

### Step 1: Install the configure executable

Configure executables are commonly bundled with libraries like fftw3. They essentially allow you to specify parameters that determine how and where the library will be built (if you desire a more detailed explanation, you can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjhscBXr_Ic&list=PLIz6U0slZNq2TS1zSUjZHgxBjAJL4nb92&index=5&t=945s&pp=iAQB), which also has a 2nd part). These executables don't come on their own - they come bundled with the source code that comprises the library. The job of a configure executable is to provide an interface that determines how [cmake](https://cmake.org/overview/) (in this case) will create a build script for the library. Of course, this means you need to download the fftw3 library. A download link can be found at [this page](https://www.fftw.org/download.html#:%7E:text=http%3A%20fftw%2D3.3.10.tar.gz%20(ftp%3A%20fftw%2D3.3.10.tar.gz)%20(md5sum)%20(4.1MB)). On Linux, you can use wget along with the link address of this library (keep in mind the link address could change with new versions):

```
wget https://www.fftw.org/fftw-3.3.10.tar.gz
```

You will end up with a tar.gz file, which is essentially a way of storing multiple distinct files in a compressed archive. You can extract the original files using the tar tool (keep in mind the name of the tar file could change with new versions):

```
tar -xf fftw-3.3.10.tar.gz
```

You should now have a folder in the current working directory containing the library sources and configure executable.

### Step 2: Configure and build the library

The configure executable takes in values that determine - or configure, if you will (hence the name) - how the fftw3 library will be built. It looks like the configure command you were trying to run is the one found [here](https://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html#:%7E:text=./configure%20%2D%2Dwith%2Dour%2Dmalloc16%20%2D%2Dwith%2Dwindows%2Df77%2Dmangling%20%2D%2Denable%2Dshared%20%2D%2Ddisable%2Dstatic%20%2D%2Denable%2Dthreads%20%2D%2Dwith%2Dcombined%2Dthreads%20%2D%2Denable%2Dportable%2Dbinary%20%2D%2Denable%2Dsse2%20%2D%2Dwith%2Dincoming%2Dstack%2Dboundary%3D2). I cannot personally confirm that this configure command works with all the options specified (it broke when I tried), but it does work given a more minimalistic approach. If you require some of the options specified, you will have to do a little tinkering - my answer is only intended to provide a general guide. Here is the command I ran:

```
./configure CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --prefix=${Path to the directory you want the library installed in}
```

To avoid the error specified in the question, make sure you **run the command in the directory where the configure executable is found (aka the library directory)**. *Also, this configuration will only build the static libraries. If you want to build the shared ones instead, you will need to add the following two options: **--enable-shared** and **--disable-static**.* As for the options specified, the **CC** option specifies the name of the program to be used when compiling the library. In this case, you want it set to the **MinGW 64-bit compiler**. If you were building the library for Linux, you would set it up to use native gcc instead (CC=gcc). The **--prefix** option specifies the directory where the library will be installed on your machine. Keep in mind, this must be an absolute path, not a relative one. Now, all you need do is run the following two commands in the library directory:

```
make
make install
```

**Make** builds the library according the the configuration you set and **make install** installs the build output to the directory you specified with **--prefix**. If you don't specify a prefix, it will likely install the build output in your system's default library directory(s), which will naturally require administrative permissions.

### Step 3: Use the library

Now that you've installed the fftw3 library on your system, you can use it in your programs. I'm not certain of this, but I've heard (from emperor's answer and other research) that you need to add the "#define FFTW_DLL" macro to the fftw3.h header file *before building the library* when compiling source code that utilizes the fftw3 library with a compiler other than MinGW. Here's how you would compile a simple program with this library using MinGW (MinGW uses practically the same flags as native gcc):

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ${source file(s)} -o ${output executable} -I${Directory where you installed the library}/include -L${Directory where you installed the library}/lib -lfftw3
```

You're now done (hopefully, but we all know nothing works during the first try in this field)!

### If you can't get this to work on Windows

No problem. In fact, I (technically) did this myself on Windows through [Microsoft's Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu)](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu/9PDXGNCFSCZV), which you can get at the Microsoft Store. After that, all you need do is copy the library from where you installed it on the subsystem to the base lib directory of wherever you have MinGW installed on your Windows machine; also copy the produced header file to the base MinGW include directory.